# I am starting out in react native, how do I install yarn correctly? Already tried google and YouTube

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

This is my first post. I am just getting started with react native and it seems that I need to download either the Yarn or npm package manager to get started with my first project.

I am using VScode as my IDE and trying to install via terminal.

I would prefer to use yarn, but either one works.

When running yarn, I am faced with the error:

```
yarn start
yarn run v1.22.10
error An unexpected error occurred: "/Users/name/projectName/package.json: Unexpected end of JSON input".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/michaelgolden/walnut/yarn-error.log".
```

or this one when using the 'init' command

```
yarn init -y
yarn init v1.22.10
warning The yes flag has been set. This will automatically answer yes to all questions, which may have security implications.
error An unexpected error occurred: "/Users/name/projectName/package.json: Unexpected end of JSON input".
```

Could someone attempt to diagnose the problem or walk me through the process of installing and running yarn correctly?

Comment: `"/Users/name/projectName/package.json: Unexpected end of JSON input` Something seems to be wrong with your package.json.

Comment: Is this before or after installing react-native?

Comment: @niles87 I don't think I've even installed react native... not sure how I can find this to confirm

Answer (score 2):

Your `package.json` file is not valid JSON. It might be missing a character, using the wrong quotes, or just have a spurious character somewhere in it.

Check with a [linter tool](https://jsonlint.com) to spot syntax errors.

Comment: That's not a valid `package.json` file as far as I know. You may want to move it aside and `npm init --auto`, then fill in the blanks as it asks you questions.

Comment: after doing `npm init --auto`  I type in `npm install <pkg>` but it returns `Sorry, name can only contain URL-friendly characters`

Comment: The name of your package defaults to the directory name you're in. If it has non-URL "friendly" characters you may need to fix that.

Comment: Ok makes sense, the directory name is just the word common. shouldn't that be URL "friendly"?  And after putting in `npm init --auto` it prompts me with `package name: (common)` what should I put after that?

Comment: Whatever you want, but I'd recommend something simple like "common" and not "my fancy project", omitting quotes obviously.

Comment: Done, but now when doing " yarn start" it gets the error, `yarn run v1.22.10
error An unexpected error occurred: "EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read".`

Comment: I appreciate you're having trouble, but it's very frustrating for us to have so few details. What are you running this in? Is it a VM or an OS of some kind? Did `package.json` somehow end up a directory?

Comment: My bad, I will try to elaborate more. Not sure if its what you're asking, but I'm running on a MacBook Pro. The goal for now is to get yarn or npm to run without errors. The VSCode project consists of a main a folder that is essentially empty with the exception of a newly created package.json. How do you tell if `package.json` ended up a directory?

Comment: I'd try this in a new directory to get a feel for it first. I don't know what you did to end up in this situation. For example: `cd; mkdir npm-test; cd npm-test; npm init --auto` then mash Enter a bunch of times to answer with defaults. That should work. If it does not there's something strange in play here.

Comment: `ls -l package.json` should give details on what that thing is. It should be a plain file. It should not be a directory.

Comment: ls -l package.json just did this, "-rw-r--r--  1 michaelgolden  staff  200 Jan 20 14:11 package.json"

Comment: and yes I followed those steps with pressing enter several times. should I be able to input 'yarn start'?

Comment: `yarn start` will only do something if you have a `start` action defined in your `package.json`. See [the documentation on `"scripts"`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts) for more details.